# QGIS says not enough space to export

Tags: qgis

I am trying to export a 100GB raster file as a .tif from its current .dat format. The CRS for the raster is EPSG:3978 - NAD83 / Canada Atlas Lambert.

This is what the extent looks like in the Export As window:
[image]

But when I try to export it I get this error message even though I have enough space on my disk for the export:

> Cannot write raster. Error code: data source creation
> Cannot create new dataset  biomass.tif:
> biomass.tif: Free disk space available is 14148063232 bytes, whereas 99558984960 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.

First, I have more than 200GB available on my disk so I don't understand why it says that I have only 14GB.

Second, I read that it might be a problem with the geographic vs projected coordinate system but can't seem to fix it.

Any insight?

Comment: Did you try setting `CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE` to `FALSE`?

Comment: Have you tried another output format?

Comment: Hi, please include the output of Raster Information tool in the question. The best way to manage this export is using the Warp (reproject) tool and defining a tif file as output, but can't be properly answered without knowing the information of the input.